KeyError in Resample when using ArcPy
I have a folder of annual land cover .tif rasters that are 30m x 30m. I'm trying to resample them to 90m x 90m using a for loop that goes through the folder. I'm not sure if I'm missing anything. My current
import os
from os import path, makedirs
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.management import *
from arcpy.sa import *

GLC_LC_outPath = r"C:\Users\ArcGis\Documents\FelixWorkingFiles\data\Analysis\Data_Preparation\GLC_LC"
GLC_LCMos_outPath = r"C:\Users\ArcGis\Documents\FelixWorkingFiles\data\Analysis\Data_Preparation\GLC_LCMosaic"
cell_size = "0.000833333333 0.000833333333"
resampling_type = "NEAREST"

reRun_GLC_Resample = 1

if reRun_GLC_Resample == 1:
    print("Running GLC_Resample")
    outPath = GLC_LC_outPath
    GLC_MosaicPath = GLC_LCMos_outPath
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk (GLC_MosaicPath):
        arcpy.env.workspace = root
        rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*")
        for rast in rasters: 
            print(rast)
            in_raster = path.join(root, rast)
            print(in_raster)
            out_name = rast.replace("Reclass_", "")
            out_raster = path.join(outPath, out_name)
            print(out_raster)
            print(cell_size)
            print(resampling_type)
            print(f"Resampling {rast}")
            Resample(in_raster, out_raster, cell_size, resampling_type)
            print(f"Resampling {rast} completed")
    print(f"All years resampled")

I run into this error:
Running GLC_Resample
InFile: GLC_Reclass_1985.tif
InRaster: C:\Users\ArcGis\Documents\FelixWorkingFiles\data\Analysis\Data_Preparation\GLC_LCMosaic\GLC_Reclass_1985.tif
OutRaster: C:\Users\ArcGis\Documents\FelixWorkingFiles\data\Analysis\Data_Preparation\GLC_LC\GLC_1985.tif
Cell Size: 0.000833333333 0.000833333333
Resampling Type: NEAREST    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [22]:
Line 301:   Resample(in_raster, out_raster, cell_size, resampling_type)

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\ia\raster_functions.py, in Resample:
Line 1618:  resampling_type = resample_types[resampling_type]

KeyError: 'C:\\Users\\ArcGis\\Documents\\FelixWorkingFiles\\data\\Analysis\\Data_Preparation\\GLC_LC\\GLC_1985.tif'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

I have also tried running it the Resample tool and it works fine, and even when I pull the arcpy script and run this:
print("Running Resample")
arcpy.management.Resample(
    in_raster=r"C:\Users\ArcGis\Documents\FelixWorkingFiles\data\Analysis\Data_Preparation\GLC_LCMosaic\GLC_Reclass_1985.tif",
    out_raster=r"C:\Users\ArcGis\Documents\FelixWorkingFiles\data\Analysis\Data_Preparation\GLC_LC\GLC_1985.tif",
    cell_size="0.000833333333 0.000833333333",
    resampling_type="NEAREST"
)
print("Finished")

It will also be successful.
So I'm not entirely sure what is wrong with my script for it to output a keyerror from the script.

You are not showing the full code. For example I'm surprised it even runs as where do you set reRun_GLC_Resample? Also there is nothing in your code that shows how the dictionary resample_types is populated? As it stands no one can answer this question.

what do you mean by the dictionary "resample_types"? Arcpy's Resample function only requires a resampling type, which i indicated set as "NEAREST." I was also unable to find any documentation of that in https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/resample.htm

Guess, based on nothing other than the code you posted: arcpy.management and arcpy.sa both contain a Resample function, so by using using wildcard imports you're unintentionally using the wrong resample function.  Generally a bad idea to use wildcard imports unless you know exactly what's in the module(s), always be specific

@mikewatt Thank you for pointing that out. I didn't realize that arcpy.management and arcpy.sa both had a Resample function... from the tool reference, i wasnt aware of a spatial analyst resample function.

The problem with the script was due to my mass imports of arcpy tools, my script was using the wrong resample function. so instead of
Resample(in_raster, out_raster, cell_size, resampling_type)

I should have been more specific and therefore use:
arcpy.management.Resample(in_raster, out_raster, cell_size, resampling_type)


This seems like a compelling argument to never use from something import *

@Vince I must agree with you there!

This ties into me pointing out the error is a dictionary error but well spotted by @mikewatt

@Hornbydd I see!, when you were talking about how the dictionary being populated, what does that mean? Is there any documentation that I could read up on?

I think the issue was that you had inadvertently called the wrong tool (because of the bulk import you  had used).  If you review the help for Resample its fourth parameter is a dictionary object. That was not get set so the error was being thrown on that. Now you are using the correct resample tool you are not causing the issue.
